How to change layer within Unity of a Gameobject via script?
I have tried several things I can find online from C3
Links I tried:

Link
Link
Link

No matter what I do, it WILL NOT change the layer of this item.
Now what I'm trying to do here, is I have a bag/inventory, and when I pick up this item, it goes into said inventory, all works well, but when I drop the item from bag, which works, and all the particular values are transferred to the new instantiation/dropped item, EXCEPT the layer is now ALWAYS default.
What I'm trying to achieve here, is when I drop the particular item, I want it to have the layer set to "9" aka, "Grabbables". But no matter what I do, or where I place the code within the dropped item logic, it is always stuck to default within the Unity editor. Even though, it does say on some instances via Debug.Log, that the layer was in fact switched to X (Desired layer) BUT when I check the dropped item VIA scene during runtime, it is always "Default".
Code/logic:
if(newClickedName == "Drop_Button"){
          

            string tempItemName;
            int tempItemAmt;
            int tempItemWeight;
            
            var itemData = inventory.GetItemList()[itemElem]; // Grabbing the element witin the inventory array:
            int correctLayer;
            tempItemName = itemData.itemType.ToString();
            tempItemAmt = itemData.amount;
            tempItemWeight = itemData.weight;

          
            GameObject itemDropped = Instantiate(itemData.GetModel(), player.position, Quaternion.identity);
            itemDropped.SetActive(true);

         
            // Edgecase to check if its Money:
            if(tempItemName == "Money")  //*NOTE* Possibly add string interpolation to determine which stack to makr already Changed: (May not matter when coming to dropping) CURRENTLY HARCODED:
            {
                // NOTE* Change force as its launchgint he item really far for money for some reason:
                itemDropped.GetComponent<GrabMoneyStack>().currentMoneyAmt = tempItemAmt;
                itemDropped.GetComponent<GrabMoneyStack>().beingDropped = true;
                // Debug.Log("test dropping here: "+ itemDropped.GetComponent<GrabMoneyStack>().beingDropped);
                // itemDropped.GetComponent<GrabMoneyStack>().alreadyChanged5k = true;
            }else if(tempItemName == "Meth")
            {
                itemDropped.GetComponent<DrugMethScript>().currentDrugAmt = tempItemAmt;
                itemDropped.GetComponent<DrugMethScript>().beingDropped = true;
               
                // int myNewLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Grababbles");
                // itemDropped.layer = myNewLayer;
                
                // itemDropped.gameObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Grabbables");

                // int LayerIgnoreRaycast = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ignore Raycast");
                // itemDropped.gameObject.layer = LayerIgnoreRaycast;
                // Debug.Log("Current layer: " + itemDropped.gameObject.layer); 

The rest is unrelated, above is the main logic for dropping the item, and I need to put somewhere in here (where it's commented out) On how to effectively change the layer to what I desire when the item drops. NOTE The above commented out code, is from the api/Google searches, don't take it specifically as I know that the Ignore Raycast will obviously be changed to whatever I desire, but it still doesn't work regardless of me changing to the proper variable names/layer names etc.

i change layers in my game, but your code doesnt seem to have any uncommented layer changing code

make sure you are viewing the object instance.  code looks fine, and if the debug log shows the correct layer, my guess is you are in prefab context or looking at the wrong object.

BugFinder, As I said in the lower explinations, the commented out code is attempts that didnt work, I was just showing that I tried all the steps I could find. Thanks though.
hijinxbassist WHat do you mean by prefab context? The wieird thing is, everything works in terms of intantiating the model thats dropped, transfering the values of amount and weight, but the layer of the gameobject, will NOT change to #9 (grabables) layer.. It keeps dropping as 1(Default) layer. Do you have any advice as to what method I could use to change the layer of the gameobject or prefab? Thanks again guys!

Are you sure the code is entering those if-else blocks? Can you reduce it to a [mcve]?

well, int myNewLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Grababbles");itemDropped.layer = myNewLayer;  will work, assuming a) that is the exact name of the layer, and b) itemDropped is not null.

Hey Sorry for the delay, havnt had time to program in a bit.. But I have done exactly that. Literally what you posted is what ive done, and I as well checked if the OBJ is null, which its comeing back that its not.. SO im extreamly confused as to why when this dropped item is intantiated, and all the values (weight, amount, etc) are added to this dropped item... But for some reason, the layer change is not Sticking... Once the item is dropped, it always says DEFAULT, which removes the desired logic needed. Any help is appreciated, and thank you for your advice.

Sorry to double comment, But wanted to express that the layer is indeed called Grababbles. The logic you posted should work as I felt.. But for some reason it is not? If I could post pictures of the results via unity editor I would..
